# CX Freeze No mpl_toolkits Module found error and Pyinstaller Cannot open self .exe when I copy it to other location other than C drive

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

When I made my exe file by following command

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn --onefile  example.py
```

It is working fine and converting my python script to the .exe but when I copy that file to other location it doesn't work and said cannot open self error ,then I tried with following attempts all failed

**I have copied all the icons requiring in my .exe to in the same folder**

Attempt 1)

```
pyinstaller --debug --onefile --noupx test.py#same error
```

Attempt 2)

[This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359547/pyinstaller-python-exe-stopped-working-cannot-open-self)

**Error(Tried to copy the error but could not because the console remains for a fraction of second and it gets closed automatically)**

```
cannotopenself (then it gives the location where I copied my newly made .exe file)
```

Then i tried with **CX_FREEZE** then again it says no tkinter module found error

I have included all the required DLL files in my main file where my script is but still it's giving tkinter not found error, have tried this below approach

**I have included tkinter but still giving this error**

**This is my setup.py file**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
# imported tkinter here also 
from  tkinter import *
import sys
import os.path
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], 'includes':["tkinter"],'include_files':['tk86t.dll','tcl86t.dll','text.ico','viewer.ico']}
# included tkinter also
# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "MINE",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "MY FILE",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("EXAMPLE.py", base=base)])
```

**Below Is the Error With image For CX FREEZE**
[image: Below Is the Error With image For CX FREEZE]

**HERE IS THE IMAGE ERROR FOR PYINSTALLER**
[image: HERE IS THE IMAGE ERROR FOR PYINSTALLER]

Now I changed my Setup.py script as below and changed the folder name from Tkinter to tkinter now it says

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from  tkinter import *
import sys
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","numpy","time","optparse","linecache","pandas",
                     "matplotlib","PIL","tk"],'include_files':['tcl86t.dll','tk86t.dll','graphs.ico','viewer.ico']}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "My file",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "MY FILE ",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("My_file.py", base=base)])
```

Now it says

[image]

Comment: You can open a command shell first, then execute the exe to see the error messages.

Comment: I tried with cx_freeze can you resolve it now

Comment: For cx_freeze, tkinter should be included in packages.So "packages": ["os", "tkinter"] and remove 'includes':["tkinter"]

Comment: @tan_an  still it says the same error now what to do?

Comment: Try removing maual inclusion of DLL files and environment path.

Comment: I removed but it's saying tkinter module not found

Comment: Can't think of anything else. This setup works perfectly for me on fairly large tkinter projects. Can you check cx_freeze version you are using ? 6.0 works for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217317/discussion-between-tan-an-and-ankur).

Comment: @acw1668 can you help in this

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with cx_freeze.

Comment: @acw1668 I have included the pictures with Pyinstaller also please see it

Comment: Is F: an external storage? Does it have enough disk space to hold the decompressed files?

Comment: Yes it has enough space @acw1668

Comment: Then I don't know why.  I have no problem using PyInstaller.

Comment: OK @acw1668 thank you for reply

Comment: mpl_toolkits is a namespace package. Inlcude following in your build_exe_options - 'namespace_packages': ['mpl_toolkits']

Comment: It worked bro put it as your answer and please upvote this post also to help many people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the method we need to follow with **cx_freeze**

a)First copy **tk86t.dll,tcl86t.dll** from python folder where you have installed python , mostly it is there in the **app_data in the local folder** , copy it where **you have your setup.py file**

b)Then in the pycharm terminal type
after installing through
`pip install cx_freeze`

c)You need to install all the libraries you have included in the main.py file in the build options in setup.py file then type
`python setup.py build` in the pycharm terminal

Below is the setup.py file as suggested by tan_an in the comments ,I requested him but he didn't post his answer so for helping the community I am doing it

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from  tkinter import *
import sys
import os.path
import mpl_toolkits
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","numpy","time","optparse","linecache","pandas",
                     "matplotlib","PIL","tk"],"namespace_packages":['mpl_toolkits'],'include_files':['tcl86t.dll','tk86t.dll']}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "Your file",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "your file",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("yourfile.py", base=base)])
```

**Now after building go to build folder and in win32 folder go to lib there change then name of Tkinter folder to tkinter
Now run your application**

Comment: Great. I am also using pycharm and never needed to copy tk86t.dll,tcl86t.dll files in the project folder. So start simply with setup.py file and only if needed, follow this step